# Display MySQL image data in PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently looking to display an image on my website using PHP. The image data is in MySQL, and I know how to display data from MySQL, but I can't figure out how to display images using insertname.png type data.

My code is currently this: (In pet_url, it basically states dogpuppyrare.png, which is a png inside my public_html inside my file manager on my hosting website.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dbuser";
$password = "dbpass";
$dbname = "db name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT pet_url FROM user_pets";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["pet_url"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You know how to retrieve the URL from the DB but you don't know how to use it then? Have you tried before asking question? PHP has its own documentation and there are a lot of tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact the field is labelled `['pet_url']`, I'm making the assumption that the data in this key is a URL, so just display the `src` using the HTML `img` tag.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<img src="' . $row["pet_url"] . '" alt="my pet image"/>"<br>"';
    }
}
```

You can read more about image tags at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp):

Answer (score 0):

Convert this line:

```
echo $row["pet_url"]. "<br>";
```

To this;

```
echo '<img src="'. $row["pet_url"] . '" alt="my pet image" /><br>';
```